# Use l'Hôpital's rule to solve

Tags: calculus

I don't even know where to begin. Help please and explain well so I can understand.

$$
\lim_{x\to e^+} (\ln x)^{1/(x-e)}
$$

Comment: First, find that this has (inderminate) form $1^\infty$.  Look in your textbook for examples of that form that have been worked out.  See what methods they used.  (SonAntonio already knew a method to use, but your textbook should have it, too.)

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

$$\left(\log x\right)^{\frac1{x-e}}=e^{\frac1{x-e}\log\log x}$$

$$\lim_{x\to e^+}\frac{\log\log x}{x-e}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to e^+}\frac1{x\log x}=\ldots$$